Can I remove an appimage file?
I have an appimage file (of the Inkscape application) in my Documents folder.
Can I delete this file? Or I deleting it will uninstall the app also?
I cannot find information about how to handle this kind of file. Is this a file like .exe in Windows (there I cannot delete the exe file).

I installed Inkscape that's why this file was created. As I am new to Linux I don't know exactly how I installed this software (I still cannot understand well how software is installed in Linux, as there are many ways and it's not as in Windows) but the result is this file in my Documents folder. I was wondering if this was like a zip file that I can delete it to save space?

i misunderstood your question. The appimage file is similar to both a zip file as it  contains all the dependencies. It is also similar to an exe file as you can run the application by double clicking it. By deleting the appimage file you uninstall the application. Inkscape will be gone if you delete the file. It won't run any more even if there is an icon left behind.

If you installed inkscape as an appimage, then after removing this file you will not be able to run  inkscape at all.
However, you don't need an appimage to install inkscape. You can always install it from the official repositories with the command
sudo apt install inkscape

Since you are new to Ubuntu, I recommend using software from the official APT repositories as much as possible.

Installing (and uninstalling) applications is the most confusing side of Linux for a new comer (at least for me). I realised that I have many options to install: by apt command, from software center, sometimes as an appimage file, sometimes as a deb file any other...At the end I don't know exactly how I installed some application? and worst I don't how to uninstall (As I don't know or remember how I installed).

Do the appimage file creates a shortcut in the Applications list? As currently I have this icon (from which I open the app).

Sometimes they do (if it is designed that way). You will most probably find the shortcut in either /home/your-username/.local/share/applications. Remove it, and install from APT. APT takes care of everything, including placing the shortcut at the proper place. In case you want to uninstall using APT at some point, APT will remove everything cleanly.

@SBachar On Ubuntu, which is a Debian-based system, .deb files are how software is installed. apt is a tool that automates the "download and install" process by downloading a .deb file for you and then automatically installing it. The software center is a graphical frontend for apt, so you can click on packages and read their descriptions, rather than using terminal commands. So .deb files, apt and the software center are functionally the same thing.

@MechMK1 The software center installs only snap apps nowadays....

Appimage is something we may call "portable application". You might have heard this term with regard to Windows. Contrary to regular applications, which are installed by unpacking the application package file and putting multiple files into multiple places in the filesystem, application in Appimage format does not require installation; you just save the Appimage file anywhere on the disk and run it. "Installing" an Appimage file is basically only creating an application launcher (desktop icon and/or menu entry) that runs the file; nothing is actually installed.
Appimage is a kind of archive file (like zip) that contains inside everything needed to run the application, but at the same time it's directly executable. You don't need to unpack it like you would with a regular archive (eg. zip) file (you can, but it's not needed); you just run the Appimage file.
So if you delete your Appimage file you will remove the application and it won't run anymore.
As for how the applications in Linux are installed, the main method is more similar to how it's done on mobile phones than in Windows (actually, the mobile phone OSes took the idea of an "app store" directly from Linux). In Windows, you search the Internet for an app, download an executable installer from a website you found and run it. In Linux, most software is stored in repositories of your Linux distribution and installed from there. In Ubuntu, a program  called "Software" or "Ubuntu Software" is your interface to these repositories (there are also more advanced programs, like command-line tool apt mentioned in the other answer, or GUI package manager Synaptic, which I prefer). You just open it and look for the application you want to install. Only if the software you want to install is not present in the repository, you may need to use Windows-like method.

Thanks for your deep explanation. So the "document" folder is the correct location for an appimage file? (I don't know how it get there). As in Windows normally you wont find exe files in Documents folder. Also, if I move this file to another folder, the app (in my case Inkscape) will still work?

@SBachar Yes, it will. AppImage files are self-contained and they will work everywhere. There is no "correct" place to put them. Put them wherever you think they make the most sense. Some people make a directory "Applications" on their Desktop and place them there, but do whatever works for you.

@SBachar "Correct" location is whatever you choose it to be :). There are no rules on this. If I were you, I would create a separate subdirectory in your home folder (eg. "AppImages") and put the file there. It will still work wherever you move it (that's the whole idea of portable application), but the desktop shortcut or a menu entry that launches the file might need updating, if it doesn't auto-update after you re-launch the application from the new location.
